# Get minimax move in string

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, minimax

I'm following this pseudocode to write my code in Java. Everything is clear and works as expected except for actually capturing the best move. It seems that my added **if condition** inside the maximizing player condition returns the last playable move in the current board. So it always plays down. How can I track the best possible move?

Here's the pseudocode

```
function minimax(position, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer)
    if depth == 0 or game over in position
        return static evaluation of position
 
    if maximizingPlayer
        maxEval = -infinity
        for each move of validMoves
            eval = minimax(child, depth - 1, alpha, beta false)
            maxEval = max(maxEval, eval)
            alpha = max(alpha, eval)

            if depth == 3
                bestmove = move (Is this correct?)

            if beta <= alpha
                break
        return maxEval
 
    else
        minEval = +infinity
        for each move of validMoves
            eval = minimax(child, depth - 1, alpha, beta true)
            minEval = min(minEval, eval)
            beta = min(beta, eval)
            if beta <= alpha
                break
        return minEval
 
 
// initial call
minimax(currentPosition, 3, -∞, +∞, true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually checking that the move is better than the others, so you're just getting the last move.

You need to check the the move's score is higher than that of the others seen before it. Since you already have `maxEval` which contains the highest score seen so far, you can simply add the check that `eval == maxEval` before updating `bestmove`.

Comment: Thank you sir, do I removed my depth condition?

Comment: @Johnnyboy No, that's important because you want it to only happen on the initial move.